# Combine jQuery and jetpack infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am using the following jQuery for an accordion effect on all my wordpress posts on the front end.

```
(function($) {
    function initAccordion() {  
        var $ele = $('.entry-content').hide();
        $(".entry-header").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $ele1 = $(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideToggle('fast');
            $ele.not($ele1).slideUp();
        }); 
    } 

    initAccordion();

    $(document.body).on('post-load', function() { 
        initAccordion();
    });     
})(jQuery);
```

I am trying to get the script to work with [infinite scroll](https://jetpack.com/support/infinite-scroll/) but I have a problem that I am not sure how to solve.

Infinite scroll works by automatically displaying older posts when you scroll to the bottom of the page. This works as intended.

The jQuery in the provided code works by displaying one post at a time if a post title is clicked. The problem is that when you scroll to a new page with infinite scroll the opened post will automatically be closed.

You can see what I mean if you use the [Live example here](http://testsite.seyoum.net/). Try to open a post, then scroll down until the URL displays `.../page/2/` and the post you opened will be closed.

How can I avoid that the opened article is closed when scrolling to a new page?

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line:

`var $ele = $('.entry-content').hide();`

to

`var $ele = $('.entry-content').not('[data-did-load]').hide().attr("data-did-load", true);`

Comment: another thing, prefer to use closest('.post') instead of parents('.post') as closest fits best in your case

Comment: This works, sort of. But I would like to have only one post displaying at a time. Example here: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: I am not completely sure if I understand what you mean with closest/parents here..?

Comment: I'm just pointing that the 'closest' method fits best in you case, just try it, change the method 'parents' to 'closest'... about the issue, can you deploy the code so I can check it and try to discover what is wrong...

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve, only with infinite scroll working so it does not close the divs when I start scrolling: http://i.imgur.com/lVUROBV.gifv and this is what happens if I use your code: http://i.imgur.com/XwpKa19.gifv I have deployed the code you suggested just now.

Comment: Basically I want one div to collapse when another one is opened. This worked before. But if I use infinite scroll, and scroll to another page, all open divs are closed.

Comment: try to change `$ele.not($ele1).slideUp();` to `$('.entry-content').not($ele1).slideUp();`

Comment: This works a lot better, but now, if I expand a post on one page, scroll to the next page and open a new post, the previously opened post does not close. I have updated the example so you can try.

Comment: strange, it seems to be working as fine as you wants to, on which browser this happens? I did test on chrome and it is fine

Comment: I tested in Chrome 50.0.2661.102 m (64-bit) and Internet Explorer 11.306 (x64)